# Failed sending mail from non existing address with spring boot: Requires password?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jakarta-mail, mime-message

I try to send email from noreply@mydomain.com. And it gives following exception: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?

This is my spring-boot application.properties:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
spring.mail.port=x
server.ssl.enabled=false
spring.mail.default-encoding=utf-8
```

And this method to send email:

```java
MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper;
helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true); // true indicates
helper.setSubject("This is subject");
helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Sender Name" + "<" + "noreply@mydomain.com"+ ">"));
helper.setTo("to@gmail.com");

Transport.send(message);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but to send an email you'd need to authenticate with the SMTP server you are using (through a username and password) which appears to be missing.

Comment: i've provided username and password when i needed to send email from my own real gmail account. However, there is no real account for no-reply. thus i cannot specify username and password.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you expect this to work?  Did you expect your mail server to allow you to send from any address as long as it's not a valid address?  Nope, that's not how it works.

See this [Gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) for how to send from a different address.   It needs to be a real address.  You can configure it to throw away eveything it receives.

If you want to do better, you'll need your own mail server that you can configure appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! But can noreply address be real? i mean is there any password i should provide?

Comment: Is Google hosting your domain with Gmail?  If so, you should be able to create an account named "noreply" and assign it a password and configure it to discard all incoming email.

Comment: No,  not gmail domain. it is my company's domain.

Comment: Then you'll need to talk to your mail server administrator and have them configure your mail server to allow you to send mail using this fake address, and to discard any messages coming in to this fake address.  How that would be done depends entirely on which mail server product you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. My ip didn't have access to send email from given domain. After getting permission from network team email sent successfully.

Comment: Advice: talk to your network Team if you can get credentials for a user that can send from this address. If your IP address will change for whatever reason you’ll get „unexpected“ bugs. Also granting access based on IP address is bad security practice. If your Net team is good they will appreciate you asking.